# How to fetch one file from two paths in unix?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, find

I am trying to fetch one file from two different paths.I used below command, seems execution fine but there is no output.

```
find . \( -path "/usr/local" -o -path "/user/local/archive" \) -name "xyz.csv"
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried with every mentioned commands but seems negative for me !

Comment: find /usr/local /user/local/archive -type f -name "xyz.csv"

Comment: _Fetch one file from two different paths_ ... Pardon?! Do you mean to **search** for a file in two different directories? or in two different directory trees?

Answer (score 3):

The reasons you don't get output:

- The dot `.` is the root of your search, so if your are not in the root directory, you won't have `/usr/local` in your search tree
- The `-path` option has to match the whole path, including the object to find, so if you have given a `-name` this name needs to be part of the `-path`, too (or be globbed with `*` at the end)

But `find` takes more than one argument as search path, so you can search like @Kamaraj wrote in his comment. In your case this is not even neccessary, as find also searches in subdirectories, thus `find /usr/local -type f -name xyz.csv` will also find `/usr/local/archiv/xyz.csv`

Comment: probably a typo from OP, but they are two different paths... `usr` vs `user`